# Search box positioning goes wrong at snapping point less than 992px?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have placed a logo, a search box and a language bar inside a row OUTSIDE, and sitting ABOVE the bootstrap navbar. This row is still within the master container of course, but it houses the 3 elements I've mentioned - 3 elements which my client and I believe are independent of the navigation bar. We felt it was better NOT to place any of those 3 things within the navigation bar. See below example:

http://www.manoj-kumar.co.uk

As I am new to the bootstrap framework, I am finding that whilst I am able to replicate the above in my own hand coded html5 and use my own media queries, I am unable to do achieve it using bootstraps code.

I think I may be over complicating things for myself, or simply not finding the correct portion of code in the bootstrap css file to edit.

What I am gunning for, is the search bar and language bar to remain side by side, but once we go lower than 992px, the two should retain their vertical positioning and not end up appearing as if they've dropped down a second row.

Since this is responsive, i intend to get the search box and language bar to shift below the logo when we enter the phone viewport sizes, something i did manage to achieve earlier but at the cost of placing the elements in areas not desired.

I would like to know what could be the issue here, or simply, what it is I should be trying in order to achieve my desired effect.

Once again, the Logo is NOT in the navigation bar, rather, it sits outside of it - above it in fact, in the top left hand corner of the container.  Furthermore, I have then placed a Search Box on the other side - to the far right, and what I have also attempted to do is add a custom Language bar next to it.  These 3 things are housed in a row.

This language bar is no more than two two text links 'EN' and 'CH' (English and Chinese), appearing as EN | CN.

As you can see from my example, it currently does not look very pretty so if anybody has any pointers in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying on a mobile device, so unfortunately I can't test. But on face value, it sounds like you may not be using one of the Bootstrap grid classes in your div elements. From my recollection, Bootstrap defines four classes. One for mobile, one for tablet, one for PC, and one for wide screen. I suspect that your issues may just be just adding the appropriate class for where the layout breaks, then possibly adjusting your class in a media query.

Comment: Recommended reading... Be sure to view on a desktop in order to get the most out of it. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Hello Jeremy, I have fixed the problem by placing the logo in a col-md-8, the search bar in a col-md-2 and the language bar in a col-md-2.

Comment: Hi Tony, glad to hear! I'd also make sure that you consider the other remaining three Bootstrap classes, if you have any more trouble on other displays (e.g. col-xs, col-s, and col-lg). If you feel that my response provided you with the correct answer, please mark accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: i tried marking accordingly - but i dont have a reputation yet heh